# Linux / PuTTY / SSH | Access denied from an external user

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been recently trying to make a collab website with a friend of mine, but when he tries to connect using any SSH client, he always gets an "Access denied" from it. But, I always get a successful login.

We have verified that the password is right, and the ports are forwarded. Everything is working, except SSH.

One weird thing is that FTP works fine.

Comment: Can you post a transcript of their attempt?

Comment: Right. This is an successful attempt (By me) [link](http://i.imgur.com/eMkrDgu.png) , and this is a failed attempt by my friend [link](https://i.gyazo.com/710fe01224aeae1516db8ec618d129d0.png)

Comment: What SFTP client are they using?

Comment: He's using "Web Matrix 3" by Microsoft (I think), and I'm using Visual Studio.
We use these for programming in my cloud server.

Comment: Is it a fresh install of PuTTY?

Comment: Yes, he is using a fresh install of PuTTY, and I am using one I've used before, and has always worked.

Comment: And I realized one mistake I made in the main post. I wrote "SFTP", I meant to write "FTP". Sorry, if it caused any trouble.

Comment: No worries. Can you post the contents of the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: Right, [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/NkqSFZv3)

Comment: It appears you may be connecting locally (192.168.x.x address) and your friend is not (84.x.x.x).  Have you checked the Pi logs to verify that your friend is actually get forwarded to the Pi?  It's possible an upstream device (your DSL or cable modem, etc.) has an open SSH port that he is hitting.  Just a possibility...

Comment: @thephez This is not the case; if so, the connection would simply timeout instead of prompting for a password.

Comment: Very strange, I know it's a silly question, is the end user definitely getting the password right?  I'd take a look at /var/log/auth.log to see if there SSH logins are recorded, and if so what the rejection reason was.

Looking at the prompt it would suggest a normal password rejection.  Silly as it sounds, how did you transmit the password to your friend?  Did it include special characters such as diamond brackets that would be stripped in IM / email?

Comment: Secondarily to the above I would advise firewalling, as the IP and operating system are public, and restricting port 22 to specific IP's (or preferably stop using passwords altogether and using a key pair), but you might want to wait until you're sure of the present issue.

Comment: @JeremiahMegel All that can be determined from the provided info is that **some** SSH server is being accessed by the friend.  There is nothing to indicate that it is actually the intended device since the SSH server isn't displaying a banner.  The OP indicates port forwarding is in use and the screenshots show 2 different IP addresses being used.  I'm speculating that this means the friend is using a public IP that is associated with a modem/router that _could_ potentially be running an SSH server.  Which is why the logs should be consulted.

Comment: Or an easy check. Stop ssh service on the box and let his friend test the ssh access. If he gets a password prompt response - he is definitively NOT hitting what they expect to.

Comment: Well, since PuTTY doesn't let you even enter a password without a valid IP, I can safely say that he is getting routed to the right address.

Comment: PuTTY doesn't let you enter a password without an _SSH server_ being on the other end of the connection.  Unless you've consulted logs or done something like @Zina suggested (stop SSH or disconnected the Pi from the network) to be certain your friend is really accessing the Pi, you **can't** safely say he is routed to the right address.  Some good, basic troubleshooting tips have been provided that are fairly trivial to check and they shouldn't be discounted.